# Apply "hover" box-shadow only to the container

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to create a `Card` component in React and CSS that already has a shadow, but on hover it gets shadow-er.

I added `box-shadow` to the container css but it seems to be applied only to its children.
Is there a way to shadow only the card-container and not its children?
For example on hover the two `p` elements get their own shadow, which I don't want.

this is the card structure in card render function

```js
<div className={"card-container"}>
  <div className="card-title">{this.state.title}</div>
  <div className="card-children">{this.state.children}</div>
  <div className="card-body">
    <p> text line one </p>
    <p> text line two </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the card css

```css
.card-container {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Card look */
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px; /* Round corners */
  border-left: 5px solid #5f37ff; /* Blue left border */
}

.card-container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

[More complete CodeSnippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/cardshadow-react-css-tlqyi)

Comment: pls remove inbetween gap to hover

Comment: remove space https://codesandbox.io/s/cardshadow-react-css-rc875

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to remove space of :hover `.card-container:hover` try this

Comment: works! Is this some kind of rule? space=children elements, no space=element itself?

Comment: you can also apply `hover` to parent `div` ```.App:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}```  https://codesandbox.io/s/so-58727013-h8hxy

Comment: yeah with space you select the children of element and what you did was like                     .card-container  *:hover that means all of .card-container childrens

Answer (score 2):

You've got your selector wrong

```
.card-container :hover
               ^
```

The space between `.card-container` and `:hover` means that the style will be applied on the elements *inside* the `.card-container`

Removing the space will give

```
.card-container:hover
```

Which applies the style when you hover the `.card-container`

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-title {
  font: 20px arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.card-container {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Card look */
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* Round corners */
  border-left: 5px solid #5f37ff;
  /* Blue left border */
}

.card-container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card-body {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card-title">card title</div>
    <div class="card-children">
      <form class="nameform"><label>Name: &nbsp;<input type="text">&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" disabled="" value="Submit">
        <div class="input-check">
          <div style="color: red;">Has at least eight characters</div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p> text line one </p>
      <p> text line two </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```